# Bash: Compose PS1 using function that returns color escape sequences

Tags: bash

I'm trying to customize my Bash (5.1.16) `PS1` by invoking a shell function.
I need the function to output a string that contains color escape sequences wrapped with the non-printing character markers (`\[ ... \]`).

It doesn't seem to work.

A simplified example:

```bash
escape_bold="$(tput bold)"
escape_normal="$(tput sgr0)"
escape_blue='\033[34m'

my_custom_function() {
    echo -e "(\[${escape_blue}\]my text\[${escape_normal}\]\[${escape_bold}\])"
}

export PS1="\[${escape_bold}\]\W \$(my_custom_function) \$\[${escape_normal}\] "
```

What I really would like to achieve is:

```
~ (my text) $
^^^_______^^^__________________________: default color
   ^^^^^^^_____________________________: blue
^^^^^^^^^^^^^__________________________: bold
```

But this is what's actually displayed:

```
~ (\[\]my text\[\]\[\]) $
```

[image]

I've also tried to escape the escape sequences, e.g. `\\\[` instead of `\[`, but it doesn't change anything. And a simple `echo` without `-e` produces a result predictably further away from what I want.

Of course, if I just put everything in `PS1` then it's displayed as I want:

```bash
export PS1="\[${escape_bold}\]\W (\[${escape_blue}\]my text\[${escape_normal}\]\[${escape_bold}\]) \$\[${escape_normal}\] "
```

However, I can't do that because in reality that hardcoded `"my text"` from the example is produced dynamically, and I want to be able to customize its color and decoration (the encompassing parentheses) depending on its value.

I've thought about setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead, but I feel that I'm close enough with `PS1` and I want to check if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I think the problem is that `\[` and `\]` are only recognized *before* the embedded command substitution is evaluated. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is really the way to go here.

Comment: Any other way to make them conditional? Basically I don't want an empty set of brackets in case `my text` turns out to be missing. For purely aesthetic reasons.